# Winsorized mean - trimming furthest points instead of both endpoints

Tags: outliers, estimators, robust, point-estimation, types-of-averages

I'm wondering if the Winsorized mean can be improved by trimming the 5% farthest points from the mean instead of trimming 5% on each endpoint.  Concretely:

Consider the [Winsorized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorized_mean), where we replace the 5% smallest values with the smallest value that remains after they are discarded, and replacing the 5% largest values with the largest value that remains after they are discarded, and then taking the mean.  This is a robust statistic with a breakdown point of 5%. Effectively, the Winsorized mean is computed based on the middle 90% of values as well as many copies of the 5th and 95th percentile.

It feels wasteful to me to discard 10% of the data if we want a 5% breakdown point.  Can we instead find the 5% of data points that are "furthest" from the mean, and replace them, so that we are only replacing 5% of the data rather than 10% of the data?  Is there a carefully worked out way to do this?

Working more or less in the framework of M-estimation, I imagine defining a loss $\ell(x)$ as follows: order $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in increasing order of $|x-x_i|$, define $d_i=|x-x_i|$, then define
$$\ell(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{0.95n} \frac12 d_i^2 + \sum_{i=0.95n + 1}^n (d_i d_{0.95n} - \frac12 d_{0.95}^2).$$
This is basically the sum of Huber losses, but where we use the quadratic part of the Huber loss for the 95% of values that are closest to $x$ and the linear part of the Huber loss for the 5% of values that are furthest from $x$.  Then, we could define a statistic as the $x$ that minimizes $\ell(x)$.  I believe this should be a robust statistic with breakdown point of 5%, and it seems like it will use more of the data than the usual Winsorized mean (95% instead of 90%), so it might be slightly more accurate (i.e., more [efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)#Efficient_estimators)) when the data is not corrupted.  Is this analysis correct?  Does this statistic have shortcomings or undesirable properties I am overlooking?  Or is it simply a "better" version of the Winsorized mean, as it appears?

Comment: Interesting questions! A potential side effect is certainly that it will more asymmaticcaly influence the tails of the distribution (perhaps only trimming the fat tail on one hand of the distribution but not on the other). To assess _shortcomings_ or _undersirable properties_ you certainly need to consider other statistics next to the breakpoint point.

Comment: In Winsorized mean the threshold is a parameter, it can be any value <50%.

Comment: @Tim, yes, absolutely - everything I mentioned can be generalized, just replace 5% with the parameter.  I found it easier to describe using a concrete number.

Comment: Winsorized mean is an L estimator not defined as a minimum but as a linear function of order statistics. What you are doing is neither an M-Estimator nor an L-estimator, you are mixing the two together. This looks like a Huber estimator with an adaptive threshold, but this threshold is not good ad all, imagine that all the outliers are grouped i.e. your data is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10], then you will cut such that the 10 are included, you will cut out larger outliers but in fact if there is just 5% outliers and they are all grouped then you include them with your scheme.

Comment: @TMat, Thank you for your comments.  That revealed that I had an error in my equation - I got the Huber loss wrong.  I've corrected it.  With the correct Huber loss, for $x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10]$, the statistic now correctly produces the result 0, as desired (i.e., it cuts out the 10's), assuming we use 20% Winsorization instead of 5%.

Comment: Will someone revert my edit? I aligned the formula with the phrase "'furthest' from the mean", but now I see that the phrase was misleading -- it would be clearer to say "furthest from a new mean"

Comment: @MattF., done!  Thank you for your attention to this question, I appreciate it.